# How to free memory after returning the pointer

Tags: c, pointers, free

```
char* stringFunction(char *astrics){

    char *string;

    string = (char*)malloc(MAX);
    string[0] = 0;
    strcat(string,"Hello ");
    strcat(string,astrics);
    strcat(string,"\n");
    return string;
    //free(string);
    
}

int main(int argc, char* argv){

    printf(stringFunction("Robert"));

    printf(stringFunction("Robert Greene"));

    return 0;
}
```

If no code is read after the return statement then how am I supposed to free the memory allocated for the pointer - string

Comment: You mustn't free the pointer in that function. The caller would not be allowed to use it making the whole function useless. It is up to the caller to free it after using it.

Comment: Please don't pass *data* to `printf` as the formatting string. Use the `%s` format and provide the data string as an argument. If you want to output a string directly, use `puts`.

Comment: You need to save the returned pointer in a variable, and pass that variable to `free` once you're done with the data.

Comment: By the way, the majority of your code could be replaced by a single call to `snprintf`: `snprintf(string, MAX, "Hello %s\n", astrics)`. The `snprintf` call could also be used to calculate the exact amount of memory needed (see e.g. [this `printf` (and family) reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) for some details.

Answer (score 2):

When you return an allocated memory bloc, you *tranfer ownership* to the caller. That means that it is the responsability of the caller to later free the memory bloc when it has finished using it. Alternatively it could in turn *transfer ownership* to its own caller (and so on and so forth...)

Answer (score 1):

Your program shouldn't free the memory until after it's finished using the memory. At the `return` statement, your program hasn't finished using that memory, because the `main` function still wants to print it! If you freed the memory inside `stringFunction`, then `main` would print freed memory.

Don't make the common mistake of thinking that you have to free pointers. You don't have to free pointers. You only have to free memory.

In this case `main` has to free the memory after it has finished using it and doesn't need it any more. This means we can't just write `printf(stringFunction(` since we need to put the pointer in a variable.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv){

    char *mystring = stringFunction("Robert");
    printf(mystring);
    free(mystring);

    mystring = stringFunction("Robert Greene");
    printf(mystring);
    free(mystring);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Extra note: instead of `printf(mystring);` you should get into the habit of writing `printf("%s", mystring);`. Otherwise if you change "Robert Greene" to "Robert %s" your program will probably crash. But if you use `printf("%s", mystring);` it will just print "Hello Robert %s"